# Como utilizar uma função friend dentro de uma classe

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Meu programa está estruturado da seguinte forma :

`Classe.cpp` **//** Implementação dos métodos da classe

`Classe.hpp` **//** Protótipos da classe

`Main.cpp` **//** Arquivo principal

Em meu arquivo `Classe.hpp` tenho o protótipo uma função `friend` :

```
friend int mdc(int, int);
```

A implementação desta função está em `Main.hpp`, a questão aqui é : como posso utilizar essa função no meu arquivo `Classe.cpp` ?

Tentei utilizando o ponteiro `this->` e :

```
Was not declared in this scope
```

Pesquisei, porém as dúvidas que encontrei tratavam de outros aspectos de funções `friend`, além disso fui veentemente indicado a não realizar a implementação de tal função dentro da minha classe. Como posso realizar isso ?

Comment: Uma função marcada como `friend` não faz parte da classe, isso apenas significa que a função friend tem acesso aos internos da classe.

Comment: Em suma : impossível realizar o que eu quero ?! ( Acho que terei de colocar a mesma em um módulo externo a main )

Comment: Isso soa como [o problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy). Faça uma pergunta com o que realmente deseja resolver.